# How to solve the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
const int ADJ_MATRIX[VERTEX_NUM][VERTEX_NUM]={   
                                                {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
                                                {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
                                                {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
                                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                                {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
                                                {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
                                                {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}
                                            };

typedef struct {
    int vertex;
    int matrix[VERTEX_NUM][VERTEX_NUM];
    int vNum;
    int eNum;
}Graph;

void buildGraph(Graph *graph){
    graph->vNum = VERTEX_NUM;
    graph->eNum = EDGE_NUM;
    graph->matrix = ADJ_MATRIX;
}
```

The error occurs in this sentence:

```
graph->matrix = ADJ_MATRIX;
```

I am new to c++. please tell me why this problem occur and how to solve it?

I want to assign ADJ_MATRIX to the matrix in `struct`.

Comment: A `const` qualifier could be sufficient if you are sure you won't modify the matrix. Otherwise, use `memcpy`.

Comment: You don't need `typedef struct { ... } identifier;` BS. You can just say `struct identifier { ... };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately, who knows...) you can't just assign one array to another in C++.

If you want to copy an array, you will need to either copy each of it's elements into a new array one by one, or use the `memcpy()` function:

```
for( int i = 0; i < VERTEX_NUM; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < VERTEX_NUM; j++ )  
       graph->matrix[i][j] = ADJ_MATRIX[i][j];
```

or

```
memcpy( graph->matrix, ADJ_MATRIX, VERTEX_NUM * VERTEX_NUM * sizeof(int) );
```

Comment: It's worth noting though that is your data contains pointers, this could be risky. Imagine if some of the cells point to other cells,  by doing a `memcpy` the addresses will not be updated correctly

Answer (score 8):

As was said, you can't assign arrays in C++. This is due to the compiler being a meanie, because the compiler can. It just won't let you do it...

... unless you trick it ;)

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct square_matrix {
    T data[N][N];
};

square_matrix<int, 10> a;
square_matrix<int, 10> b;
a = b; // fine, and actually assigns the .data arrays
a.data = b.data; // not allowed, compiler won't let you assign arrays
```

The catch? Now the code needs some little things:

```
const square_matrix<int, VERTEX_NUM> ADJ_MATRIX={{ 
                                               // blah blah
                                            }}; // extra set of braces

typedef struct {
    int vertex;
    square_matrix<int, VERTEX_NUM> matrix;
    int vNum;
    int eNum;
}Graph;

void buildGraph(Graph *graph){
    graph->vNum = VERTEX_NUM;
    graph->eNum = EDGE_NUM;
    graph->matrix = ADJ_MATRIX; // no change
}
```

And to access the cells, now we need to use `graph->matrix.data[1][2]`. This can be mitigated by overloading `operator[]` or `operator()` for `square_matrix`. However, this is now getting terribly close to the new `std::array` class, or the Boost equivalent `boost::array`, so it might be wise to consider those instead.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not assignable.  You can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(graph->matrix, ADJ_MATRIX, sizeof(graph->matrix));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign your variable address of a constant data, 
try using

```
memcpy(graph->matrix,ADJ_MATRIX,sizeof(ADJ_MATRIX));//using sizeof(graph->matrix) is safer.
```

Comment: sizeof(ADJ_MATRIX) will suffice

Comment: well, `sizeof(variable)` is better then `sizeof(data_type)*num_elements` as it is ---more--- flexible

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an array to another array. You will need to copy the elements from the source to the destination index by index, or use `memcpy` to copy the data. Array assignment like this is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an array in assignments. You may use cycles or `memcpy` instead

```
memcpy(graph->matrix, ADJ_MATRIX, VERTEX_NUM * VERTEX_NUM * sizeof(int));
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < VERTEX_NUM; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < VERTEX_NUM; ++j){
        graph->matrix[i][j] = ADJ_MATRIX[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown, because `int matrix[VERTEX_NUM][VERTEX_NUM]` in a structure definition means that each structure will have a 2D array of integers of the predefined size and `matrix` is going to be pointing to its first element. The thing is that `matrix` cannot be assigned to an arbitrary address, because it's a const pointer i.e. its value (the address it's pointing to) cannot change.

You have 2 options here: you can either use `memcpy` or some stl algorithms to copy the `ADJ_MATRIX` into matrix directly or you can declare `matrix` as a pointer and do the assignment that is currently produces an error.

The latter can be done in the following way:

```
typedef struct {
    int vertex;
    const int (*matrix)[VERTEX_NUM];
    int vNum;
    int eNum;
}Graph;
```

Thus you can do `graph->matrix = ADJ_MATRIX` assignment, but you won't be able to modify the individual items in `matrix` due to constness. This means, `graph->matrix[0][1] = 3;` is not allowed, while you can read the elements freely.